# can't receive notifications from Notification Center

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I have a simple app:
first VC:

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("test"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
}


override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondVC")
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

second VC:

class SecondVC: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(SecondVC.testFunc(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name("test"), object: nil)
}

@objc func testFunc(notification: NSNotification) {        
    print("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
}

deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

}

and I never saw the "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that you're posting the notification in a **viewDidLoad** from the first view controller, then later on **viewDidAppear** you're pushing your second view controller and then subscribing to the notification center. At that point your notification has already being fired, hence you're not receiving it. Your second view controller will only receive notification that are fired post its subscription to the notification center. Create a timer that will fire the notification in a couple of seconds after view did appear pushes your second view controller and you will see it working

Comment: can you write an example? I didn't understand

Comment: Your second view controller will only receive notifications that are posted after its subscription to the notification center. In your code example you're posting a notification first and then presenting your second view controller and subscribing to receive the notifications from the notification center. The reason why you're not receiving any notifications should be clear now, as no further notifications are posted after your second view controller has subscribed to receive them. What you need to do is make sure your notifications are posted after you subscribe to notification center.

Answer (score 1):

In your above mentioned code, you are posting the notification first & then adding the observer for it. So, in order to call ***testFunc*** method you need to addObserver first then post the notification.

You can add few seconds delay in firstVC for posting Notification.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10.0) {
           NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("test"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
      }
}
```